# Function hook address copied incorrect

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook, reverse-engineering

I am trying to hook an application with a dll I injected. At the moment the dll contains a hook, a function trampoline and an empty function. However the target application crashes when the hooked function is called. I looked what went wrong and it seems that the replaced jump instruction jumps to an unknown place I didn't specify. Upon closer inspection I realized that this unknown address look remarkably similar to the correct one. It seems like the unknown address is the correct address shifted to the right with 4 junk bits in front of it. So my question is how did this happen and can I correct this?

```
#define FUNC_JMP    0x00433504
#define FUNC_ADDR   (FUNC_JMP+1)

// Trampoline
__declspec(naked) void setup (void) { ... }    

void hook (void)
{
    DWORD protect, buf;
    DWORD adr = (DWORD) ((BYTE*) &setup - (FUNC_ADDR + 4));

    VirtualProtect ((void*) FUNC_ADDR, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &protect);
    memcpy ((void*) FUNC_ADDR, &adr, 4);
    VirtualProtect ((void*) FUNC_ADDR, 4, protect, &buf);
}
```

Before 0x00433504: `jmp    dword ptr ds:[0x1F8BAC4]`

After  0x00433504: `jmp    fword ptr ds:[0x10B51DC]`

Actual value of adr: `0x0B51DC2D`

TLDR; Why is the value I memcpy'd incomplete and shifted 4 bits to the right.

Comment: This does not look like C++ code. Do not add irrelevant tags.

Comment: @Olaf It can be either C++ or C as you probably know. Do not add irrelevant comments.

Comment: An answer might depend on the actual language, as you probably know. If not, you apparently do not know C++. However, you are invoking undefined bahaviour, so there is no use in further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `jmp dword` instruction has a 2-byte opcode, you only skip one byte of this. 
(See the `#define FUNC_ADDR   (FUNC_JMP+1)`

So you are overwriting a part of the instruction, and ignoring a part of the address.
This is also indicated by the second instruction you posted, because now it's an `jmp fword` instead of `jmp dword`.